# Skip Django Allauth " You are about to sign in using a third party account from Google" page

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

How can I skip the page and automatically logged in users, when they clicked on **Login in With Google**.
[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to set up `SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET=True` in your configuration (by default it's `False`). according to https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html:

> **SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET (=False)**
>
> Controls whether or not the endpoints for initiating a social login
> (for example, “/accounts/google/login/”) require a POST request to
> initiate the handshake. For security considerations, it is strongly
> recommended to require POST requests.

Comment: SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET=True inside settings.py worked for me.Thanks.

Comment: This should definite be the answer as it uses the builtin configurations of allauth

Comment: For those looking for the specific security reasons of why to not use `SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True`, see the [Changelog for django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/main/ChangeLog.rst#security-notice-3) and [Google's blog post about open redirect abuse](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2009/01/open-redirect-urls-is-your-site-being).

Comment: Is there a way to skip that view and still do a POST request? Please explain if I misunderstood something

Answer (score 16):

To bypass the "*You are about to sign in using a third party account from Google*" page in [django-allauth](/questions/tagged/django-allauth), you can use a form to directly initiate the login process via a **POST** request. This is considered more secure as it prevents **CSRF** attacks. Here is the example code snippet:

```html
<form action="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit">SIGN IN WITH GOOGLE</button>
</form>
```

Alternatively, you could set **`SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True`** in your configuration, but this is not recommended due to security risks, including the potential for **Open Redirect Attacks**. For more information on why **POST** is preferred over **GET** for login requests, please refer to the **`django-allauth`** [**security-notice**](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/main/ChangeLog.rst#security-notice-3) and the [Google's blog post on open redirect abuse](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2009/01/open-redirect-urls-is-your-site-being).

Thanks to **[Niko Chaffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6837070/niko-chaffin)** for providing useful information in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72162359/skip-django-allauth-you-are-about-to-sign-in-using-a-third-party-account-from/72162783#comment134943488_73300330).

Comment: Nice. This absolutely worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me, I was stuck with the ugly continue page for a couple of hours. This should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just Add this:
**SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET=True**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: your answer is already posted. Therefore, please upvote answers and do not write them again. If you answer, please provide as much information as possible, e.g. a link to the documentation. Please see the answer of nad2000.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32759682)