"Sign In Via Google" intermediary step in django-allauth
I am implementing Google OAuth into my Django project. I set up settings.py and everything, I got this <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}">Continue with Google </a> link, but when I click it, it takes me to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/" page which looks like this:

Only after clicking continue button I am redirected to the correct page when I can choose Google profile I want to log in with:

How can I get rid of the intermediary step and go directly to selecting a Google profile after clicking the link?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72162359/skip-django-allauth-you-are-about-to-sign-in-using-a-third-party-account-from/73300330#73300330
